# Input pattern block links and special characters

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I have promote box which allow users to input text and send it to admins.

## Logic

1. I want to block links and any special characters.
2. User only are only allowed to input texts `a-z` (capital or not doesn't
   matter) and numbers `0-9`
3. Input is not required.

## Code

[Documentation](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/message-box#prompt)

```
this.$prompt('Input your message here.', 'Tip', {
    confirmButtonText: 'OK',
    cancelButtonText: 'Cancel',
    type: 'Thank You!',
    inputPattern: /[A-Za-z0-9]+/,
    inputErrorMessage: 'Invalid Message'
}).then(({ value }) => {
    // do my things...
}).catch(() => {
    // do my things...
});
```

## Question

What is the right value for `inputPattern` in order to achieve my logic?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you're missing the two rules that say your test should match the entire string:

`/^ .... $/`

Also, you want the input not to be required, so we need to exchange the `+` (1 or more) symbol to `*` (0 or more).

So, for example:

```js
var testcaseInputs = [
  "niceone", // yes
  "niceone1", // yes
  "NiceOne1", //yes 
  "nice-one-1", // no
  "", // yes
  " ", // no
];
var inputPattern = /^[A-Za-z0-9]*$/;

testcaseInputs.forEach(testcase => {
  console.log(testcase, new RegExp(inputPattern).test(testcase));
});
```

if you also want strings with spaces, use this regex instead  `/^[A-Za-z0-9\s]*$/` (includes `\s` that accepts whitespace characters)

Comment: Thank you but there is small issue, this code forbid space as well. we all you in one sentence words are separated by spaces :)

Comment: Haha just noticed, amended for you at the bottom :)

Comment: No worries @mafortis :) If you want a useful cheatsheet and testing area, try https://regexr.com/ - it's quite good! Not a promo haha